# JSON mappnig unxepectable case

Tags: java, json, scala, fasterxml, spray-json

Earlier I used `import com.fasterxml.jackson` in my application.
Because I used akka http, I wanted to try live with Marshal/Unmarshal and `spray.json.toJson.compactPrint`.
Without extra package (`com.fasterxml.jackson`) dependency.

But I stuck on simple case

old working code:

```
...
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

val obj: AnyRef = new Object()
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

val json = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj)
```

new code:

```
import spray.json._

val obj: AnyRef = new Object()
val json = obj.toJson.compactPrint
```

This cause exception

> Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for AnyRef on
>   obj.toJson.compactPrint

Help please!

upd:

this is real part of code - for better understand what i need
it works well. 
com.fasterxml.jackson mapper does not have restriction to write AnyRef to json string

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

object mapper {
  private val _mapper = new ObjectMapper()
  _mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

  def get: ObjectMapper = _mapper
}

import akka.actor.{Actor, Props, ReceiveTimeout}
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{ContentTypes, HttpEntity, HttpResponse}

object RequestHandler {
  def props(ctx: ImperativeRequestContext): Props = Props(new RequestHandler(ctx))
}

class RequestHandler(ctx: ImperativeRequestContext) extends Actor {

  import context._

  import concurrent.duration._

  setReceiveTimeout(30.second)

  def receive: Receive = {
    case ReceiveTimeout =>
      ctx.complete(HttpResponse(500, entity = "timeout"))
      stop(self)

    case x: AnyRef =>
      ctx.complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, mapper.get.writeValueAsString(x)))

      stop(self)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you complain about. Spray JSON library as it is typical for a Scala library is more typesafe than Jackson. Particularly `toJson` works basing on the compile-time type rather than rune-time type. And obviously there is no safe way to transform any `AnyRef` (aka `Object`) to a JSON because there might be any object of any type behind that variable. Consider following example:

```
val obj: AnyRef = new Thread()
val json = obj.toJson.compactPrint
```

To Spray JSON this code looks exactly the same as your example. Obviously you can't write `Thread` to JSON. The difference is that with Jackson you will get some kind of a runtime error. With Spray JSON it will not even compile. If you use some specific types that can be converted to JSON safely - Spray JSON will work for you.

If the question is that you want to have some generic method that accepts arguments and as one of the steps does conversion to JSON, then you should use generics and constraints to specify that type as in:

```
def foo[T : JsonWriter](bar : T) = {
    //do something

    bar.toJson.compactPrint

    //do something more
}
```

**Update: more realistic example**

Here is an example that compiles for me and runs as I would expect:

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._ 

case class Foo(i: Int)
implicit val fooFormat = jsonFormat1(Foo)

case class Bar(ii: Int, ss: String)
implicit val barFormat = jsonFormat2(Bar)

def printJson[T: JsonWriter](obj: T):Unit = {
  println(obj.toJson.compactPrint)
}

printJson(Foo(42))
printJson(Bar(123, "this works!"))
```

Comment: @HoTicE, it would help me to help you if you provided more details on how exactly this "_not works_". I've added a self-contained example that works OK for me. You also might be interested in reading the docs on the [Spray-JSON GitHub page](https://github.com/spray/spray-json)

Comment: i have an actor where in receive it is case  msg: AnyRef =>
because it is no matter what is comes - i need json of it.
in previous version of code was ObjectMapper from com.fasterxml.jackson.
And mapper.writeValueAsString(x) does it well.

If you try val msg: AnyRef = new Object() 
and then printJson(msg)
you will see same exception as before - "Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for AnyRef" 
Exception if function gets AnyRef as parameter

Comment: @HoTicE, the statement that "_no matter what is comes - i need json of it_" is impossible to implement. What if an instance of `Thread` class is coming there? What is the objects graph has a cycle (so JSON tree is infinite)? There is **no safe way** to build JSON from arbitrary object and this is exactly what Spray and it says it to you at **_compile time_**.  The Jackson based code didn't really work with arbitrary objects as well. It worked only with a subset of the objects that could actually come. For Spray JSON to work you should somehow provide the list of all possible types explicitly.

Comment: in update i wrote working code that parse AnyRef to Json without any restriction

Comment: @HoTicE, I think you miss my argument. For a more concrete example consider following simple class `case class AnyWrapper(var value: Any)`. Now consider following recursive value `val w = AnyWrapper(null); w.value = w`. Or a bit deeper `val w1 = AnyWrapper(null); val w2 = AnyWrapper(w1); w1.value = w2`. What would happen if your `RequestHandler` would `recieve` such `w` or `w1`? The code will fail at runtime. Again the claim that you can reasonably serialize any object to JSON is false. Spray JSON just make it more explicitly false by failing to compile rather than failing at runtime.

Comment: Your code works because **_in practice_** you can't receive any object. Still for Spray JSON to compile you should provide some kind of an evidence that every object that can be received can be serialized. There are several possible way to do this and which one is better depends on your overall architecture.